# How to optimally index streaming data received for an indefinite amount of time?

Tags: c++, indexing, streaming

I'm developing an application that receives and records sensor data to a file. The data is received in the form of discrete, variable size blocks, that can simply be written to a binary file.

However, in order to add file seeking capabilities during playback, I also need to store a limited, but configurable amount or indices to specific data blocks written.

Assuming that the recording can be run for any given amount of time, and stopped at any random time, what's the best way to always keep the index array pointing to equidistant data blocks within the recorded file?

Here is a code example

```
class SensorStream
{
    public:

        FILE *file;
        int *indices, currentIndex;

        SensorStream(int port, int numIndices)
        {
            file = fopen("/tmp/sensor.dat", "wb");
            indices = new int[numIndices];
            currentIndex = 0;
            //Connect to sensor and register data block callback
            //...
        }

        void onDataReceived(void* data, int size)
        {
            indices[currentIndex++] = ftell(file);
            fwrite(data, size, 1, file);
            //How to keep index array
            //up to date and equidistant?
        }

        ~SensorStream()
        {
            fclose(file);
            delete[] indices;
        }
};
```

For instance, in an ideal case after recording 1 million data blocks and using 1000 indices, the index array would include the file offsets to data blocks #0, #1000, #2000, etc... Which could of course be located anywhere in the file as the block themselves can have variable size.

So far, my best idea is to start indexing every single data block and once filled the index array, halve it so that it only contains indices from its even positions. Then, continuing indexing every 2 data block received.

By repeating this process, halving the index array every time it's filled and following by indexing every i * 2 data blocks, I believe I could achieve an acceptable result. However, this approach could result in a number of used indices half of what's originally specified (in my example of 1000 indices selected, only 501 would be used if the recording is stopped right after halving the index array).

Since this is only an idea I've come up with, Is there any better way to keep my indices up to date and equidistant given these constraints?

Thank you very much for your time and support.

Comment: `int *indices,` -- You already started off on the wrong foot by not using `std::vector<int> indices;`

Comment: While the data block can be of varying size, they do have some meta-data to tell you how large each block is? Like the `size` argument to your receive function Just keep a manual counter of the size written to the file. When you write a block, increase the size counter with the size of the block. When you need to save the "index" just save the current value of the size counter. If you're worried about overflowing even an unsigned 64-bit integer, only store the size since the last stored size, and reset it each time you store the size.

Comment: Also, you're really programming more "C with classes" than "proper" C++. Use vectors and C++ file streams.

Comment: `file = fopen("/tmp/sensor.dat", "wb");` -- Putting this in the constructor could lead to issues.  `SomeStream s(1, 1);` -- Just doing something that looks this benign, you've attempted to open a file, and possibly have an object that is in a "bad state" if the file cannot be opened for some reason.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Thanks, that's a good idea: as the size of each block is indeed known, it could be used to keep the indices equidistant regarding their size and not only their arriving order. It still leaves the question of what to do once all the indices has been used up. And sure! the snippet was more of a simplified example to illustrate the problem :)

Comment: Don't store the index in memory (unless you actually need it in memory), but in a second file? Use a fixed-size structure for the index file, so each index can be easily found.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I assume you mean writing to a second file the offset of every received data block? I don't need the indices in memory at all times, but since the use case is only seeking (on a seekbar), I believe it would be somewhat overkill to store every single one of them, specially in a long recording.

Comment: Do you need to seek *all* of the data received, from the beginning of time? Or is it okay to seek only the latest data, like the last day or hour or so? Perhaps keep only the last X hours in memory, and store the earlier in the index file. When seeking past the in-memory data, load from the file (which with fixed-size records should be relatively simple and fast).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If our requirement is to have the same amount of frames at all times, then
we can solve this problem by using a fixed-size priority queue of indices. The priority of any index `i` is the the:

```cpp
max( distance( i, predacessor(i) ),
     distance( i, successor(i) ) )
```

However, this requirement is overly strict for the use case, so you can see the *Alternative Solution* below.

#### Example

Say we have a size of `4` and add indices to it over time. We want these indices to be equidistant.
The following example shows how we gradually go from:

- an empty list to
- a list with equidistant indices (distance 1) to
- a list with equidistant indices (distance 2)

```cpp
list: []; list: []

push(1)
push(2)
push(3)
push(4)

// the notation for the queue elements is:
//   index:priority
// lower priority gets popped first
list: [1, 2, 3, 4]; queue: [2:1, 3:1, 1:inf, 4:inf]

// To correctly evict elements, we should allow pushing one past the capacity.
push(5)
list: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]; queue: [2:1, 3:1, 4:1, 1:inf, 5:inf]

// We have exceeded our capacity, so we now pop() the least distant element.
pop() -> 2

list: [1, 3, 4, 5]; queue: [4:1, 3:2, 1:inf, 5:inf]

push(6)
list: [1, 3, 4, 5, 6]; queue: [4:1, 5:1, 3:2, 1:inf, 6:inf]
pop() -> 4

list: [1, 3, 5, 6]; queue: [5:1, 3:2, 1:inf, 6:inf]

push(7)
list: [1, 3, 5, 6, 7]; queue: [6:1, 3:2, 5:2, 1:inf, 7:inf]
pop() -> 6

// we have now reached a point where the distance between all elements is 2
list: [1, 3, 5, 7]; queue: [3:2, 5:2, 1:inf, 7:inf]
```

#### Implementation Details

The list of elements can be a linked list, because we need fast random removal and access to both neighbors.
The standard library conveniently provides `std::list` for us.

The priority queue can be implemented as a `std::vector` + binary heap operations from `<algorithm>`, but we need to be aware of some issues:

- When a node is pushed to the `list`, the priority of the preceding node is recomputed. This means we need to pop it from the heap and re-insert it.
- When a node is popped from the `list`, the priority of neighbours needs to be re-computed, because their distance changes.
  This means that we remove the node itself from the heap, and we re-insert the neighbors.

Here are the relevant operations:

- `std::push_heap` to push an element
- `std::pop_heap` to get the element with the lowest distance
- `heapify` to restore the heap property for an element which's priority has been recomputed

Out of these, we only need to implement `heapify` ourselves.

#### Complexity

`push` and `pop` are a combination of linked list operations, which are *O(1)*, and heap operations which are *O(log N)* where *N* is the number of elements.

---

See also: [Wikipedia article on Binary heaps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_heap) (fantastic read if you want to learn how to implement a priority queue using a binary heap)

## Alternative Solution

If we don't require a fixed amount of indices at all times, then your original idea could also work.
Basically, we grow to double the amount of required indices, eliminate every second, and then half the frequency at which we add new indices.

#### Example

Say we have a size of `>= 4` indices that we want to track:

```cpp
list: []

push(1)
// ...
push(8)

list: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
remove_odd_indices()
list: [1, 3, 5, 7]

push(9)
push(10) // ignored, we only respect every 2nd push now
list: [1, 3, 5, 7, 9]

// ...
push(15)
list: [1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15]
remove_odd_indices()
list: [1, 5, 9, 13]
```

#### Implementation Details

We need a container with `N * 2` capacity.
Resizing is not strictly needed, because we can keep track of the amount of indices with an `int` ourselves.
We could even use a plain array here.
Furthermore, we need to keep track of our step size, which is doubled after every `remove_odd_indices`.

The amount of indices changes over time, but we can uniformly access the mover regardless using: `i * amount / N`, where `N` is the minimum amount, and `amount` is the actual amount of elements at any time.

Comment: Amazing answer. Exactly what I needed, very detailed and informative. The kind of solution that helps one to become a better engineer. Thank you very much!